# What is the looping code to generate traces for a multi-category x-axis bar chart?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-python

I have spent days trying to plot a bar chart of the following data on plotly using python and jupyter notebooks:

```
site    end_date    weight  diversion_weight    count
0   All Sites   2019-11-30  19609.32    15387.52    977.0
1   All Sites   2019-12-31  13188.50    10283.40    658.0
2   All Sites   2020-01-31  21975.01    17502.41    1124.0
3   All Sites   2020-02-29  1933.06 1535.96 111.0
4   Site 1  2019-11-30  8351.48 5864.38 491.0
5   Site 1  2019-12-31  6746.97 4761.47 393.0
6   Site 1  2020-01-31  12040.58    8748.83 745.0
7   Site 1  2020-02-29  1193.33 900.73  72.0
8   Site 2  2019-11-30  11257.84    9523.14 486.0
9   Site 2  2019-12-31  6441.53 5521.93 265.0
10  Site 2  2020-01-31  9934.43 8753.58 379.0
11  Site 2  2020-02-29  739.73  635.23  39.0
```

With each time series on the x axis having the following for each site: a bar for diversion_weight that overlays a bar for weight

I'd prefer to not have a series of subplots.

I saw [this post](https://community.plot.ly/t/grouped-bar-chart-on-a-dataframe/12833/3) as a potential guide but could not figure out how to adapt the code to my problem.

Dict for the data:

```
from pandas import timestamp

   dfplot = {'site': {0: 'All Sites',
      1: 'All Sites',
      2: 'All Sites',
      3: 'All Sites',
      4: 'Site 1',
      5: 'Site 1',
      6: 'Site 1',
      7: 'Site 1',
      8: 'Site 2',
      9: 'Site 2',
      10: 'Site 2',
      11: 'Site 2'},
     'end_date': {0: Timestamp('2019-11-30 00:00:00'),
      1: Timestamp('2019-12-31 00:00:00'),
      2: Timestamp('2020-01-31 00:00:00'),
      3: Timestamp('2020-02-29 00:00:00'),
      4: Timestamp('2019-11-30 00:00:00'),
      5: Timestamp('2019-12-31 00:00:00'),
      6: Timestamp('2020-01-31 00:00:00'),
      7: Timestamp('2020-02-29 00:00:00'),
      8: Timestamp('2019-11-30 00:00:00'),
      9: Timestamp('2019-12-31 00:00:00'),
      10: Timestamp('2020-01-31 00:00:00'),
      11: Timestamp('2020-02-29 00:00:00')},
     'weight': {0: 19609.32,
      1: 13188.5,
      2: 21975.010000000002,
      3: 1933.06,
      4: 8351.48,
      5: 6746.97,
      6: 12040.58,
      7: 1193.33,
      8: 11257.84,
      9: 6441.53,
      10: 9934.43,
      11: 739.73},
     'diversion_weight': {0: 15387.52,
      1: 10283.400000000001,
      2: 17502.41,
      3: 1535.96,
      4: 5864.38,
      5: 4761.47,
      6: 8748.83,
      7: 900.73,
      8: 9523.14,
      9: 5521.93,
      10: 8753.58,
      11: 635.23},
     'count': {0: 977.0,
      1: 658.0,
      2: 1124.0,
      3: 111.0,
      4: 491.0,
      5: 393.0,
      6: 745.0,
      7: 72.0,
      8: 486.0,
      9: 265.0,
      10: 379.0,
      11: 39.0}}

    dfplot
```

Comment: can you add a code to reproduce your dataset ? A responder would like to copy-paste your code and be able to get the dataset.

Comment: Thanks @Arman -- I pasted the dict into the body of this post. Is this what you need? I'm a recent Stata to Python convert so I apologize for the delay.

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'm hoping this works now.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with a Tutorial (either Python or Pandas) practicing the examples. It will give you ideas to help you solve your problem.  pandas as well as Python has excellent documentation